# How do I save or send information from 2 forms to a single class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an inconvenience.
I have two different classes, one for each form with its respective text box and I want to store the information in the class called CustomerRegistrationModel without the need to create a CustomerRegistrationModel object in each class.

The idea is to save the information of the 2 forms in RegistroClienteModel and then send that to the database

registrousuario11 and registrousuario22 are similar.

code and image::

```
class RegistroClienteModel{



 String contrasena ;
  String get Contrasena => contrasena;

  String correo ;
  String get Correo => correo;

  set setContrasena(String usucon) {
    contrasena = usucon;
  }

  set setCorreo(String corre) {
    this.correo = corre;
  }


String apodo;
  String get Apodo => apodo;

set setApodo (String usuapodo) {
    this.apodo = usuapodo;
}

String apellido;
  String get Apellido => apellido;

set setApellido (String usuapellido) {
    this.apellido= usuapellido;


int edad;
 int  get Edad => edad;

set setApellido (int usuedad) {
    this.edad = usuedad;


}
```

---

```
class registrousuario11 extends State<>{
Widget ContrasenaF2(Contrasena){
  return new Container(
      child: new TextFormField(
        // validator: (value)=>value.length < 6?"Contrasena muy corta": null,
        controller:Contrasena,
        obscureText: true,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
      //    hintText: 'Ej:123xxx',
          labelText: 'Domicilio',
        ),
      )
  );
}

Widget CorreoF2(Correo){
  return new Container(
      child: new TextFormField(
        controller: Correo,
        // validator: (value)=>!value.contains("@") && value.contains("mail")?"Correo Invalido":null, //para validar si el correo esta correoto
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.email),
          // hintText: 'Ej:xxx@gmail.com',
          labelText: 'Apodo',
        ),
      )
  );
}

Widget  ConfirmarContrasenaF2(ConfirmarContrasena){
  return new Container(
      child: new TextFormField(
        controller: ConfirmarContrasena,
        //obscureText: true,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.check),
        //  hintText: 'Validar su contraseña',
          labelText: 'Edad',
        ),
      )
  );
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Formulario2"),
          centerTitle: true,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: new Container(
            //padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,right: 10,// Para que el teclado no este sobre el texto
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0), // Margen a todos los componentes(textfield,botones etc...)
            child: new ListView(

                children:[
                  SizedBox(height: 8,),
                
                  SizedBox(height: 28,),
                  CorreoF2(Correo),
                  SizedBox(height: 28,),
                  ContrasenaF2(Contrasena),
                  SizedBox(height: 28,),
                  ConfirmarContrasenaF2(ConfirmarContrasena),
                 
                 
                ]
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
}

class registrousuario22 extends State<>{}
```

---

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first
you can implement that suing state management as provider
[get started with provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

you can store class object on provider and make them available on widget tree

or you can use this package to create form [reactive form](https://reactive_forms:%20%5E14.1.0)

it's contain Good docs to get started
here example show you how to start

```
final form = FormGroup({
  'first': FormControl(validators: [Validators.required]),
  'second': FormControl(),
  'third': FormControl(),
  });
```

this how to use it .  very similar to TextField

```
    class Example extends StatelessWidget {

  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);



  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ReactiveForm(
      formGroup: form,
      child: TextField(
        formControlName: 'first',
        validationMessages: {}, //here can add message to show user if feailed required
      ),
    );

  }

}
```

and now you can create many form and access to information to any form

hope this help you to create forms

Comment: Provider is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from one class to another using with constructor.